# VBA Access SQL SELECT Query only returning one record

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm working with VBA in Access 2010 and I have an odd problem. I'm trying to pull records from a table, but my SELECT query is only returning a single record.

There are three records in the table, but the recordset is only getting the first one.

Here's my code.

```
Dim cc As String 
Dim DB As Database 
Dim rst As recordset 
Dim sqlstr As String 
Dim e As Integer 

cc = CmbClass.Text
If cc = "" Then Exit Sub 

sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM Students" 'WHERE CCode ='" & cc & "'"

Set DB = CurrentDb 
Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset(sqlstr) 
'Debug.Print rst.Fields(0)
e = rst.RecordCount 
Debug.Print e 
If e = 0 Then Exit Sub
```

The value of e is continually 1, not 3. As you can see I originally had a more complex SQL string, but I've cut it down to the most basic while trying to troubleshoot, yet the problem persists. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks,

Tam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From memory you need to issue a `rst.MoveLast` before you can reliably get the record count like this:

```
sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM Students" 'WHERE CCode ='" & cc & "'"

Set DB = CurrentDb 
Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset(sqlstr) 
rst.MoveLast
e = rst.RecordCount
```

Also you might want to consider using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Students` and reading the value from the recordset instead of moving through the records to get the count. Using this query should be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the `rst.MoveLast` fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Another method is `DCount`.

```
e = DCount("*","Students","CCode ='" & cc & "'")
```

no playing around with recordsets until you really need to